# Memcpy unique_ptr to vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr, memcpy

I am trying to write the memory area described by the *unique_ptr buffer* and *uint32_t bufferSize* into the *std::vector value*. When I use std::memcpy for this, I get the following warning:

> ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’ writing to an object of type ‘class std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator >’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]

```
int ReadByName (std::vector<unsigned char> &value, const char handleName[], std::ostream &out, const long &port, const AmsAddr &server)
{
        uint32_t bytesRead;

        out << __FUNCTION__ << "():  ";
        
        if (this->handle == 0)
            handle = getHandleByName(out, port, server, handleName);
        if (bufferSize == 0)
            bufferSize = getSymbolSize(out, port, server, handleName);

        const auto buffer = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>(new uint8_t[bufferSize]);

        const long status = AdsSyncReadReqEx2(  port,
                                                &server,
                                                ADSIGRP_SYM_VALBYHND,
                                                handle,
                                                bufferSize,
                                                buffer.get(),
                                                &bytesRead);
        
        if (status) {
            out << "ADS read failed with: " << std::dec << status << '\n';
            return 2;
        }
        value.clear();
        value.reserve(bufferSize);
        std::memcpy(&value, buffer.get(), bufferSize);
        return 0;
}
```

What would be the correct way to approach the problem?

Regards
Tillman

Comment: `value.assign(buffer.get(), buffer.get() + bufferSize);`?

Comment: Off topic but... `buffer` should be initialized using `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(new uint8_t[bufferSize])` rather than `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>(new uint8_t[bufferSize])` -- note the extra `[]`.

Comment: Thanks, i think this is what i was looking for @Jarod42.

Answer (score 4):

> What would be the correct way to approach the problem?

It would be to read into a vector directly, rather than a separate array that you later copy.

> In case the read operation with AdsSyncReadReqEx2() fails, value would have already been cleared.

Don't clear `value`, but use another vector. If operation succeeds, move-assign the intermediate vector to `value` which doesn't require copying of the elements.

Even better: Don't pass `value` into the function at all, but return the vector and use more modern error handling mechanism than a plain error code. You can use for example exceptions or something similar to the proposed `std::expected`.

Comment: It seems the issue is that `AdsSyncReadReqEx2` expects `uint8_t*`, but OP wants to return it as `unsigned char`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That should hardly be an issue given that `uint8_t` is an alias of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Here I see a problem: In case the read operation with AdsSyncReadReqEx2() fails, value would have already been cleared. The buffer allows me to wait for the result of the read operation before overwriting the stored value.

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes, here's the correct code

```
    value.clear();
    value.resize(bufferSize);
    std::memcpy(value.data(), buffer.get(), bufferSize);
```

First mistake, `&value` does not give you the data area of the vector for you to write into `value.data()` does that.

Second mistake, `reserve` does not change the size of a vector so you are writing into an empty vector. Use `resize` to change the size of a vector.

**EDIT**

Obviously what eerorika says is true. You can adapt the above code to pass a valid pointer to the vector data to `AdsSyncReadReqEx2` and do away with `buffer` completely.

```
 value.resize(bufferSize);
 const long status = AdsSyncReadReqEx2(  port,
        &server,
        ADSIGRP_SYM_VALBYHND,
        handle,
        value.size(),
        value.data(),
        &bytesRead);
```